# MySQL cannot connect [using password: YES]

Tags: mysql, debian

My new user cannot connect to MySQL database.

> Enter password: 
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'newusr'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But I can connect by using:

> mysql -u newusr -pPassword

Yes I Flush the Privileges 
After some readings i grant some privileges for test

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newusr'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
>
> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'newusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';

no diferents here.
On the server I have 4 users for web purpose (create at the begining) and they connect correct.
All new users have a problem. 
Can someone tell me what happen?

There are No anonymouse users, No test default database. I use mysql_secure_installation but no progress on this time.

Since the last time I create a user i twice upgrade MySQL.
I dont see any diferent betwin new and old user by

> SHOW GRANTS FOR username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just for reference*, below are the steps to be followed for creating a new account in MySQL:

a. **Create user `user` with password as `password`** where `localhost` is the MySQL host:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

b. **Grant access to the user** on `db` database and `table` table.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'db' . 'table' TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

OR, to grant access to all database or table, use `*`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

c. For changes to be effective, you have to **reload all the privileges**.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Such a simple solution And how stupid mistake. THX Works greate

Comment: OK There was another problem. 
There was special characters @ \ and = in the password. With these characters all login attempts ended in error.
After changing special characters both ways to create user and grant permissions work.
Anyway, thanks for pointing to the causes of errors.